# creating an array of tuples with matched elements - mnist data

Tags: python, numpy

I have a csv data, the first column of the data is 'label' and columns after the first one to the end 784 column contains a representation of an image (28*28) format.

I am trying to create an array of these two. I get it created but the format I like is not appearing.

This is the code I used:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with open(dir_path+'train0.csv', 'rU') as csv_file:
    for df in csv.reader(csv_file):
        label=np.array(df[0], dtype=float)
        pixels=np.array(df[1:], dtype='float').reshape((28,28))
        print zip((label, pixels))
```

which results:

```
[(array(0.0),), (array([[   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,
           0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,
           0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,
           0.]]),)]
```

> however my desired format is:

```
(array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32), array([5, 0, 4, ..., 8, 4, 8]))
```

Please note that I switched the label and pixel values from my problem to the desired output.This is basically an array of tuple of two entries.

Is this because I am using  csv. I cant get it fixed. Any help will be appreciated

> **Here is the solution I got finally:** :

```
filename=dir_path+'train1.csv'

def load(filename):
    # read file into a list of rows
    with open(filename, 'rU') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        rows = list(lines)

    # create empty numpy arrays of the required size
    data = np.empty((len(rows), len(rows[0])-1), dtype=np.float64)
    expected = np.empty((len(rows),), dtype=np.int64)

    # fill array with data from the csv-rows
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        data[i,:] = row[1:]
        expected[i] = row[0]

    training_data = data, expected
    return training_data

print load(filename)
```

> Result:

```
(array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]))
```

ref: stackoverflow.com/search?q=formatting+my+mnist+tuple

Comment: where are you expecting to get that second array from? If you have 785 columns, the first being a 'label', and the rest making a 28x28 array, where is the label in your desired format and where does the second array come from?

Comment: The first column of the csv file is label.

Comment: lxop, please note that array values are '0' in this case. My desired output has different values.

Answer (score 0):

With a sample 'csv' text:

```
In [41]: txt = b'''label1 1 2 3 4
    ...: label2 8 9 10 11
    ...: label3 10 11 12 13
    ...: '''
```

and a compound dtype:

```
In [46]: dt = np.dtype([('label','U10'),('image',float,(2,2))])
```

`genfromtxt` can load the columns as label and 3d image fields:

```
In [47]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=dt)
In [48]: data
Out[48]: 
array([('label1', [[  1.,   2.], [  3.,   4.]]),
       ('label2', [[  8.,   9.], [ 10.,  11.]]),
       ('label3', [[ 10.,  11.], [ 12.,  13.]])],
      dtype=[('label', '<U10'), ('image', '<f8', (2, 2))])
In [49]: data['image']
Out[49]: 
array([[[  1.,   2.],
        [  3.,   4.]],

       [[  8.,   9.],
        [ 10.,  11.]],

       [[ 10.,  11.],
        [ 12.,  13.]]])
```

You can vary the `dtype` to suit your needs.

```
dt = np.dtype([('label','U10'),('image',float,(4,))])
```

Comment: that helps but its is still not in the correct format as my desired output.

Comment: I am looking for somethign like this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=formatting+my+mnist+tuple

Comment: Looks like you just want a tuple with 2 arrays.  e.g. `(data['image'], data['label'])`.

Answer (score 0):

**this is the solution**

```
filename=dir_path+'train1.csv'

    def load(filename):
        # read file into a list of rows
        with open(filename, 'rU') as csvfile:
            lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            rows = list(lines)

        # create empty numpy arrays of the required size
        data = np.empty((len(rows), len(rows[0])-1), dtype=np.float64)
        expected = np.empty((len(rows),), dtype=np.int64)

        # fill array with data from the csv-rows
        for i, row in enumerate(rows):
            data[i,:] = row[1:]
            expected[i] = row[0]

        training_data = data, expected
        return training_data

    print load(filename)
```